# C/C++ interfacing, generation of static library

Tags: c++, c, linker, static-libraries

I'm trying to refactor an application that's made of two relatively independent parts, one part is written in C (let's call it part A), and the other part in C++ (part B). Part A contains the main logic of the application, and part B contains utility functions.

Initially, everything was compiled with g++, and there were a few C++ instructions spread in part A in order to use part B classes and methods. The whole thing was linked with various C++ libs that were needed in part B.

I want to clearly separate those two parts. I have created a new module (interface.h interface.cpp that defines a few functions with a C interface, that call the C++ stuff I need). Now partA only uses the functions define in interface.h in order to access the services provided by part B.

Now I'd like to generate a static library from part B. I've tried something along those lines:

First, generation of the library:
`ar rcs libpartB.a interface.o partB1.o partB2.o ...`
(`PartBX.o` are the (c++) object files I generated from part B, interface.o defines exactly the functions I need in part A).

Then, I compile my main application:
`gcc -o main partA.o -lpartB`

Unfortunately, it doesn't work! When I create the static lib, obviously I still miss some code: for instance, the C++ library and other libs I needed in my code. I'd like to pack everything I need in libpartB.a, so that I don't have to rely on external stuff when I link partA.o to libpartB.a.

So my questions are: 
 - how to add the needed external libs to libpartB.a, and not more than what my code really needs?
 - does my approach make sense?

UPDATE:
 I managed to link my application with a command such as

`g++ -o main partA.o -lpartB -lxml++ -lglib2 -l... -l...`

What bothers me with this approach is that I need to change my makefile for part A whenever the people working on part B decide to use a new library in their code. As much as possible, I'd like to separate this into two separate projects, with two different Makefile, and a simple contract ("interface.h") that defines the interface. I guess that'll do...

Comment: As ever, work with a minimal implementation to prove the methods, before investing massive time converting an entire suite.

Comment: At least for static linking, this basic approach mostly doesn't work. As a general rule, if there's C++ code anywhere in the program, then `main` must also be compiled/linked as C++, so you get the C++ startup code. Offhand I'm not sure if putting the C++ code into a .so file would do the job (on Windows, using a DLL would do the trick). Alternatively, rename your current `main` to something like `mymain`, and write a new `main` (in a C++ source file) that does nothing but `return mymain(argc, argv);`. This gives you a `main` in C++, but your C code intact.

Comment: Use `g++` to link the program.  Also, be aware that C++ interfaces can exhibit *source* compatibility, but do not exhibit *binary* compatibility.  If ever you modify any of your C++ interfaces then you need to recompile everything.

Comment: I suggest using CMake instead of doing all that stuff manually.